# Program freezing up when reading from socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am having an issue with trying to read a socket in a java program. I am using a separate thread that runs a JFrame, but I use the main thread for the socket management. I can connect to the server and send info with no problem, but when I try to read info from the port the program is stuck on reading the port.

The class I am using for reading the port is DataInputStream and I am just using the

```
     readLine()
```

method to read from the socket. Is there another way to read from the socket that would fix this problem?

Comment: [`InputStream.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())? Aside from that, are you sure your server is sending a "line"? Recall that a line ends with a newline. [Are you sure the socket has data available to be read?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) Note also that [`DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()).

Answer (score 0):

If `readLine()` is blocking, the peer isn't sending a line. Possibly the peer isn't sending anything, or else there is no line terminator.